# Google Android in-app Billing V3 : security vulnerability?

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Based on the AIDL interface (in-app billing V3), we can easily get past purchases of the user with :

```
//interface method
Bundle getPurchases(int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, String continuationToken);

// in activity   
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

I wonder if we replace **getPackageName()** by an other application package name, we can get billing information.

ex:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, "com.king.candycrushsaga", "inapp", null);
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

To establish the Google Play IAB Service connection your apk must be signed with the same key as the one uploaded through the google play dev console. I presume at this point it obviously knows what data you should have access to. You will probably get BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR for all of your service calls which use the wrong package name.

I am speculating here so feel free to test this and report it if you are able to get hold of the data for other apps!

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that key is checked in the "bindService" method ?

Comment: i don't know for sure, maybe not, I think this will succeed regardless. Only once you start polling for products and trying to make purchases is the check probably made.